# How can I run unit tests with Maven as if they are in a JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, junit

We recently had a bug caused by some code assuming that a classpath resource could be opened as if it were a regular file.  This code was covered by unit tests which passed, because that assumption happens to hold both in Maven and Eclipse.  But in production, that code was in a JAR in the service's WAR, and obviously didn't work.

We fixed the bug but I'm not quite satisfied because I can't see how to ensure that it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests are run using [Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/).  This happens during `mvn test` and "test" occurs before packaging.  But if you want to run tests after `mvn package`, you should use [Failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

Here's some [very relevant documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) about configuring the classpath.  By default, it will put `${project.build.outputDirectory}` in the classpath, but you should be able to prevent that by setting [classesDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#classesDirectory) to some other directory.  Then you can add your own jar as either an [additionalClasspathElements](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#additionalClasspathElements) or perhaps a [dependenciesToScan](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#dependenciesToScan)

Comment: Failsafe still uses the `./target/classes` classpath as opposed to just using the generated jar: [link](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html)

Comment: A bit hacky, but I think it'll work, and I can't think of a better option.

Comment: @yshavit me either :)